# Hide editor while keeping add media button in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, images, media-library

How do I remove Editor in custom post type keeping the Add media button. When I used as following in custom post type declaration, it removes the Add Media button and I don't need editor in my post type.

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just [use the media uploader/flow directly](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/)? Maybe in a custom meta box.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But is there a native way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses the function [wp_editor()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) and there are no parameter that will disable the textarea (what i can see). So i think that you can just hide it with some css.

```
function wpse_78595_hide_editor() {
    global $current_screen;

    if( $current_screen->post_type == 'custom_post_type_name' ) {
        $css = '<style type="text/css">';
            $css .= '#wp-content-editor-container, #post-status-info, .wp-switch-editor { display: none; }';
        $css .= '</style>';

        echo $css;
    }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'wpse_78595_hide_editor');
```

Comment: I had the same situation as the OP, and also found nothing, ended up using CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Wordpress 4.0 (or earlier) has removed the need for the editor, as I was able to easily not include it.

Comment: Please [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/171912/edit) your answer; explain how you removed the editor, while keeping the Add Media button.